# Работа с вкладками

Tags: c#

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии создавалась новая вкладка и там был какой либо компонент!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WPF**:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Name="tabControl" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource tabItemContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
                <DockPanel Margin="7" DockPanel.LastChildFill="False">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="Информация для пользователя" Foreground="sc#1.000000, 0.250141, 0.333404, 0.884413" TextAlignment="center"   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14pt"   DockPanel.Dock="top"/>
                    <Expander Margin="0,0,0,10" DockPanel.Dock="top" Background="White" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Name="reportExpander" ToolTip="Нажмите, чтобы развернуть">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="bold" FontSize="12pt" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis">Составленный отчет</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header> 
                        <FlowDocumentReader Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="reader" IsFindEnabled="False" IsTwoPageViewEnabled="False" IsScrollViewEnabled="True" ViewingMode="Scroll" Background="Gray" Zoom="60" ZoomIncrement="5" MinZoom="25" MaxZoom="100">
                            <FlowDocument Name="flow" ColumnWidth="800" IsColumnWidthFlexible="true"></FlowDocument>
                        </FlowDocumentReader>
                    </Expander>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**C#**:

Добавить табик:

```
/// <summary>
/// Список отчетов, выводимый на форму в виде TabItems.
/// </summary>
public class SomesReportList : ObservableCollection<SomesReportList >{}

/// <summary>
/// Список отчетов
/// </summary>
private SomesReportList reportList = new SomesReportList ();

// Связываем отображение отчетов на форме со списком отчетов
this.tabControl.ItemsSource = this.reportList;
```

Найти FlowDocument на табике:

```
ContentPresenter cp = tabControl.Template.FindName("PART_SelectedContentHost", tabControl) as ContentPresenter;
// получаем ссылку на элемент отчета
FlowDocument flowDocument = (FlowDocument)tabControl.ContentTemplate.FindName("flow", cp);
```